# Where can I get additional NetBeans color themes

Tags: netbeans

How can I change netbeans color scheme to some predetermined theme? I don't want to set each value manually. When I was working with Eclipse I had to download some plugin. Does anything similar exist for Netbeans? or perhaps there is some website with all themes to download?

edit: I will expand my question a little bit. I am specifically looking for Oblivion color theme for Eclipse http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=1 or very similar.

Comment: http://blog.mixu.net/2010/05/03/syntax-highlighting-color-schemes-for-netbeans/ http://wiki.netbeans.org/LookAndFeel

Comment: Finding adequate themes for NetBeans has always been a sore spot with me. It also seems like there is no focus on this in the community. Each release that comes out still has the same list of boring themes. It's nice that there is a few people out there making themes. I really wish there was a http://StudioStyles.info like site for NB's themes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can import a theme, here are a couple of examples:

- [Desert Colour Scheme for NetBeans](http://marcfearby.com/computing/desert-colour-scheme-for-netbeans)
- [Dark Color Scheme/Theme for PHP](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic11387.html)

Answer (score 48):

I've made a small site for NetBeans lovers to exchange their favourate color schemes. Here is my site: http://netbeansthemes.com Now, we have 13 color schemes total, and everyone has a screenshot for you to preview. Hope you can find one you like, and welcome you to upload your favourate.

Comment: wonderful. wondering if there is any chance to import from/to netbeans and phpstorm? I really like the dracula theme on phpstorm.

Comment: I uploaded a new theme (VS 2012 Dark) for Java yesterday but it hasn't shown up yet. Is there a delay of some kind?

Comment: @AndreasÅgren Sorry, your theme is published now. I post uploads myself manually. So, there is some delay exactly.

Comment: @Charles Thanks! Is there any way I can update it (I made some changes to it today) and perhaps change the embarrasingly incorrect title? ;)

Comment: @AndreasÅgren just upload it again with the same theme name and author name, and I'll update it for you.

Comment: @Charles How could I install downloaded theme?

Comment: Instructions for installing them would be appreciated

Answer (score 28):

Around 40 themes are available for free at http://svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder/. If you are not satisfied with them, you can build one of your own with the on-line tool accompanied with it.

Comment: This is a good spot for themes, and a nice tool!

Comment: Hey, where to send the check!

Answer (score 5):

Probably you looking for http://codesleepshred.com/dark-netbeans-themes-oblivion-revival-and-monokai/

Answer (score 3):

I plan on converting the some of the themes found on http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/. You can find them at https://github.com/Zren/Netbeans-Themes. Right now I've run through the xml files and marked where what the equivalent of the Eclipse palette goes. Right now I've only focused on Java.

It uses a Python script to compile the zips from an easier file arrangement. I might eventually create a skeleton theme that could be used for a converter, depending on how annoying xml parsing is.

Right Now I've finished (Updated Sept 2012):

- Monokai
- Retta
- Sunburst
- Vibrant Ink
- Zenburn